# How can I keep network shares (not on my PC) in sync?

Tags: windows-7, sync, network-shares

I have two Windows NTFS network shares that I would like to keep in sync. I am connecting to them from Windows 8. I would like it to be as close to real-time as possible. I can use an app if there is no built-in commands in Windows 8 available.

The searches I've done in the past have not turned up any great solutions. What I would love is if you could map two network shares to the same folder if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 folders, say Folder1 & Folder2 both shared. Then use a program like [FreeFileSync's](http://www.freefilesync.org/) Realtime Sync to  copy changes from one directory to the other. The program is rather straightforward to use and will copy across a file 10 seconds after it is edited (by default).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that program but was not impressed with the real-time sync feature being a separate program and felt sort of clunky. Lately I use a combination of Robocopy and Dsynchronize.